# Renamed property not being saved correctly in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to update the properties of my entity. For example, in the TestEntity class:

```
class TestEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $testMe = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTestMe(): ?string
    {
        return $this->testMe;
    }

    public function setTestMe(string $testMe): self
    {
        $this->testMe = $testMe;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I made a mistake with the snake_case naming convention, and I want to rename the $testMe property to $test_me."

In the updated text, I made some corrections to the capitalization and punctuation, and rephrased some parts of the text for clarity.

"I renamed the $testMe property to $test_me everywhere in the TestEntity class:

```
class TestEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $test_me = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTestMe(): ?string
    {
        return $this->test_me;
    }

    public function setTestMe(string $test_me): self
    {
        $this->test_me = $test_me;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

However, after updating the code, i noticed that both the old and the new properties are being returned in an array (using API-Platform):

```
[
  {
      "test_me": "test",
      "testMe": "test",
      
    }
]
```

I have cleared the cache and Doctrine cache, and there is no other use of testMe in the project except for the getter and setter methods in the TestEntity class. I am not sure where the old property is being saved and why. Can you help me understand this issue?"

My composer.json to see my installed Bundles

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "api-platform/core": "^3.1",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "*",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.18",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.3",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
    "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.16",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/messenger": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/notifier": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/sendgrid-mailer": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.2.*",
    "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "*",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "php-http/discovery": true,
      "symfony/flex": true,
      "symfony/runtime": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "6.2.*"
    }
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48"
  }
}
```

Comment: Run the command `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and see what it says.  I'm guessing your database still has either the old column or the new one.  You did not mention anything about migrations.  Just changing the entity it not enough.

Comment: "I have completely reinstalled my database and rebuilt the projects without any old migrations. There is a column proj_nr, it comes out as projNr and proj_nr as property. No duplicates in the Entity. I am curious about this issue and will attempt to reproduce it on a clean test project." Output of the prompt was: Nothing to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony Serializer also looks to the public-getter method.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform2/serialization-tricks#controlling-field-names-serializedname

Try  `#[SerializedName('test_me')]`

Comment: I think you gave me the right hint. I will check it out at work soon.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that the doctrine cache contains outdated information about the entity. In this case, you can try clearing the doctrine cache by running the following command in the console

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

This command removes all doctrine metadata cache files, allowing doctrine to rebuild the cache with the most recent information.

Comment: Cache successfully deleted, but still the problem. Thanks anyway